# CommonsMetadata extension: tracking categories not updating

Tags: mediawiki

I have enabled the [CommonsMetadata](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CommonsMetadata) extension on [a Miraheze wiki](https://polytope.miraheze.org/) I administer. My hope was that it would generate a [Files with no readable license](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Files_with_no_machine-readable_license) category, as in Wikimedia Commons and related projects. Although this did got added to the [Tracking categories](https://polytope.miraheze.org/wiki/Special:TrackingCategories) list, two days later and the category is still empty.

I know for a fact there's files that haven't been properly categorized: [here's an example file I uploaded](https://polytope.miraheze.org/wiki/File:Test.txt). Even then, these categories aren't getting added.

Is there something I haven't properly configured? Or does this extension not work like that?

Comment: Apparently [Miraheze commons](https://commons.miraheze.org) has this extension enabled, and there's certainly untagged files, but even their categories are empty. So maybe this issue is on them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `$wgCommonsMetadataSetTrackingCategories` to true.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have direct access to this setting, but I'll ask the Miraheze admins to enable it. I'll accept this answer if it works.